# Bootstrap 3 glyphicon rendering as "..." within Handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, templates, twitter-bootstrap-3, handlebars.js, glyphicons

I'm trying to use a glyphicon within a Handlebars template, specifically within an `each` block.

`{{#each data}}
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
{{/each}}`

This results in `...` rendering instead of the icon:

[image]

If I place the same `span` tag outside of the `each` block (within the same template), it renders just fine.

[image]

Is there some other way that the glyphicon needs to be included for it to be rendered properly within a Handlebars template?

Comment: Check for `data` might be `empty`,

Comment: @kumkanillam what check are you referring to?

Comment: Referring `data` property